# Servlet streaming mp4 for html5 video in chrome

Tags: java, servlets, video-streaming, html5-video

i'm trying to stream a movie (mp4 or ogv based upon browser) from a Java servlet to be used in a HTML5 webpage. After doing some research here, i found out that i need to support ranges. In most of the examples there is a reference to http://balusc.blogspot.be/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html. This seems to work as it should for IE and Firefox except for some socket write errors that get thrown, but the movie plays in these 2 browsers.

In Chrome however, the movie starts off fine, but most of the times it simply goes blank when it's mp4 or just freezes when it's ogv after playing for a while. I'm not getting any errors tho.

I'm using the source code from [Balusc](http://balusc.blogspot.be/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) for my servlet. The only thing I added was logic to determine a subfolder based upon the file requested, but this was allready happening before i added my own stuff.

Help will be greatly appreciated, cause it is driving me crazy that it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't without any clear reason.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: I have the same problem in PHP, but in FF - after a while video stops playing and the progress bar jumps to the end. Although, in other browsers Chrome, Opera, Safari it is ok. I`m using HTTP_RANGE headers to parse requests and Content-Range: bytes and Content-Length headers for response. Why the hell somebody needs IE nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome try to low byte-range to read from stream for response (ex.: you set 10240 bytes, as it seems from the source Balusc, set this value to 1024*8/7/6), some people told that it helps to play video exactly in Chrome.